# Summary of OData standard for a minimal, read-only implementation

Tags: json, odata, standards, atom-feed, atompub

The [OData specification](http://www.odata.org/media/30001/%5Bms-odata%5D.pdf) is long. Even the "[OData Core](http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData.html)" document is pretty long.

So, how about a condensed summary of what a read-only OData publisher needs to implement at a minimum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start. An OData service provides an HTTP endpoint that:

- MUST understand "`Accept`" headers
- MUST support Content-Type header, and MUST support ATOM format (optionally JSON)
- MAY return a service document (list of collections) to `GET /` (10.1.1)

  - If ATOM (AtomPub?) format, the hierarchy is `service/workspace/collection/title`
- MUST return descriptions of collections to requests like `GET /Customers` (10.2)

  - If ATOM, the hierarchy is `feed/entry/content`
- MUST return descriptions of individual entities to requests like `GET /Customers(3)` (10.2.1)
- MAY return individual properties of individual entities for requests like `GET /Customers(3)/Name` (10.2.2)
- MUST make available a [CSDL](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/common-schema-definition-language-csdl/) schema description wrapped in an EDMX document (10.1.2)

  - This SHOULD be available at `/$metadata`
- MAY support any of these queries (10.2.3)

  - Filters (limit rows returned): `Products?$filter=Price lt 10.00`
  - Select (limit fields returned): `Products?$select=Rating,ReleaseDate`
  - Order-by: `Products?$orderby=ReleaseDate asc, Rating desc`
  - Top, skip: `Products?$top=5&$skip=2`
  - InlineCount (include an entity count): `Products?$inlinecount=allpages`
- MUST (?) provide a list of relationships for an entity (10.2.4): `Products(0)/$links/Orders`
- MUST provide an entity count (10.2.5): `Products/$count`
- MAY support other formats with `$format` specifier (10.2.3.7)

When an ATOM feed is returned (such as for a collection), it needs to conform to some OData conventions: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/atom-format/ For example:

- Types used are "`edm:String`" etc.
- `link` elements are used generously
- `content` elements either contain content inline (eg, text data), or link to it (eg, images, binary files) with `src=` attribute.

When a JSON feed is returned, it similarly follows certain rules:

- http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/json-verbose-format/

URLs are encouraged to follow this scheme:

- http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/url-conventions/

Comment: URLs are not required to follow the conventions. It is perfectly valid to have an OData service which doesn't use parenthesis for key lookups, but instead uses some other form).

Comment: This is a good summary. Where can I understand more about what relationships according to the OData standard and what different endpoints should an implementation support in order to adhere to the standard (version 4.0)?